# Adding Scrollbars in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

This is kind of a really nooby question, and I think I already know the answer, but:

Can you add Scrollbars to the side of a `<div>`?

Comment: if you add **css** tag then yes, overflow:scroll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### CSS

```
div {
   height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Wdj3M/).

You give an explicit height so the `div` doesn't expand to fit its content.

If you only want horizontal or vertical scrolling, use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` respectively.

If down the track you want the extra content to be *hidden*, use `overflow: hidden`.

The default for `overflow` property is `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
overflow:auto;
```

or force the scroll area even when content doesn't overflow by:

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add scroll bar in a div

```
 <div style="overflow:auto; height:556px;width:564px;">
 </div>
```