# How to add a scrollbar style in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles, scrollbar

This is a functioning scrollbar style that I use inside the HTML but I need to put it in my JavaScript code.

```css
.large-2 {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 50%;
}

.large-2::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 2px 0;
  background-color: #404040;
}

.large-2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

.large-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #737272;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div you would add a class name for your scroller:

```
div {
       height: 100px;
       overflow: auto;
    }
```

Refer to this link: [Adding Scrollbars in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414786/adding-scrollbars-in-html)